# Is it possible to modify android manifest xml to allow backup of application that originally could not be backed up?

Tags: android, backup

may I please ask?

Let's assume I have access to android manifest xml. Some applications, like banking apps have option to be backed up disabled. I would like to back them up with `adb backup` anyway. Can I modify android manifest xml to allow the backup? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want force the app to allow backups you need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml from `android:allowBackup="false"` to `android:allowBackup="true"`. However, if you edit the AndroidManifest.xml the signature of the app will no longer be valid. This means that after rebuilding the apk you need to sign it with your own key and reinstall it. During this all app data will be lost.

I found this guide a while back and successfully used it on another app. I'm not sure whether banking apps have any protections against this though.

https://dalvikplanet.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-force-any-android-app-to-allow.html